# Change button image at runtime in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

I am creating a button with CCMenuItem in cocos2d. I want the button image to be change whenever i tap it. Is there anyway to do that at runtime.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a CCMenuItemSprite you can specify normal and selected sprite. Just specify them:

```
CCMenuItemSprite *item = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:@"1.png" selectedSprite:@"2.png" target:self selector:@selector(foo)];
```